# Display buttons over image with Display:Block property

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image displayed on the center of the page using this CSS code:

```
      .img{
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position:relative;
         }

      .btn{
       position:absolute;
       margin-top:10%;
       margin-left:-27%;
         }
```

HTML:

```
    <img src="12345.png" class="img"></img>
        <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
        <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn1' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
        <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn2' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
```

How can I make the 3  tags which are also images display over the image? It worked just fine before  I added  *display:block*.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="position:relative">
<img src="12345.png" class="img"></img>
<div style="position:absolute">

        <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
        <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn1' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
        <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn2' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>

</div>


</div>
```

try this... will help u much better ....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried display flex over the overall div. If you don't have an overall div for the images I would add one and set it to display: flex; And if you want the images in front of the first image add z-index: -1; to the first image. I am newer to CSS but I believe this will work.

```css
.spacing {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacing">
  <img src="12345.png" class="img"></img>
  <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
  <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn1' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
  <a href="http://google.ro"><img src="pin.png" class='btn2' width="30px" height="48px" alt="http://google.ro" ></img><a>
</div>
```

```css
      .img{
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position:relative;
        z-index: -1;
         }

      .btn{
       position:absolute;
       margin-top:10%;
       margin-left:-27%;
         }
```